# Unit testing custom StyleCop rules

Tags: unit-testing, stylecop

I'm wondering what's the best way to go about unit testing custom SytleCop rules. I've read [this](http://sergeyshishkin.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!9F19E53BA9C1D63F!232.entry) but am hoping there's a better solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's a project called StyleCop Contrib [at CodePlex](http://stylecopcontrib.codeplex.com/) where they have unit test for custom rules.